# iOS 11 search bar has no top padding when status bar is hidden

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, ios11

When setting status bar to **hidden**

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

and initialize a *plain* `searchController` using

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

It appears normal if unedited, however if you click into the search bar, the navigation title will hide and there is little padding between the search bar and top edge, which is very visually broken.

Solution is appreciated.

### Minimum example

https://github.com/DJBen/SearchBarNoTopPadding

[image]

Comment: Show more about how the search controller is configured, please.

Comment: @matt `let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)` is all I had. I've included this line in the question.

Comment: Does your main view (not shown in the screen shot) underlap the navigation bar?

Comment: @matt The vc is a plain table view controller nested in a navigation view controller with no further configurations. Let me put up a minimum demo in a gist real quick.

Comment: No need. I can reproduce.

Comment: @matt updated screenshots and uploaded a git repo

Comment: Fixed it, see revised answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in iOS 11. To work around it, add these lines to your code:

```
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

The alternative is to go on doing this the old way, e.g. make the search controller's search bar your navigation item's `titleView`. That does still work fine in iOS 11.

Comment: It doesn't solve the root problem but it's a nice workaround. Thanks!

Comment: I agree that it doesn't solve the underlying problem. You should file a bug with Apple.

Comment: self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []

This line worked for me!